# Different topologies on rings?

Tags: commutative-algebra, topological-rings

Suppose we define topological a ring $A$ with $I$-adic topology. Then we can talk about neighbourhood {$x+I^n|$for some $n>0$, and $x\in A$} in $A$. But I don't know how to describe the structre of discrete topology on a ring?

In analysis, we can use metrics to define discrete topology, but in general algebra, we don't have such tools. I guess we can make the discrete topology by requiring $I^2=(0)$. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "describe the structure", exactly?  Are you asking whether there is an ideal $I$ such that the $I$-adic topology is the discrete topology?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

We can make the discrete topology by requiring $I=(0)$.

Comment: But that would be too trivial. At least we need $I\neq (0)$.

Comment: @YuyiZhang I don’t see a lot of choice here.  If a local base at $x$ is $\{x+I^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ then $x$ is an isolated point iff $x+I^n=\{x\}$ for some $n$, that is iff $I^n=\{0\}$. But then we can use $I=\{0\}$ instead of $I^n=\{0\}$ and the topology “don’t  notice” this.